# C# Reflection on UnitOfWork / Generic Repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

This seems like an age-old question, but simply can't find what I'm looking for. Here's my current code with things I've tried.

```
private async Task<T> HandleFileCreate<T>(Guid tableId, IFormFile file, DocumentType documentType)
            where T : DocumentLibrary
        {
            // This works fine and gets the correct type
            Type repoType = _unitOfWork.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name + "Repository").PropertyType;

            // This works fine and creates an instance of my document
            T document = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            // Throws up error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType);

            // Throws up error: "Object does not match target type."
            repoType.GetMethod("Create").Invoke(repoType, new object[] { document });
        }
```

It seems a bit chicken and egg because I can't invoice "Create" it seems without the CreateInstance, in which I can't do because of IoC.

This is really annoying because I've already got an instantiated property in _unitOfWork which relates directly to my relevant GenericRepository, I just can't figure out how to access it? I shouldn't even have to re-instantiate it.

Comment: Is your Repository generic? What is your IoC container? If you are trying to do DI why not just pass IRepository<T> as an input parameter? I would not really try to do this if you really need it use a your service locator don't use Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: Yep, my Repository is generic and takes in the ApplicationDbContext.. IoC is handled by MVC Core. Sending in the entire repository of T isn't ideal as this function is called at Controller level. Will look into Service Locator!

Comment: What do you mean with Sending the entire repository of T isn't ideal? You're just passing a reference anyway... If you have a `Repository<T>`, you should just pass it in the at `ConfigureServices` with `services.AddSingleton`

Comment: If two people are saying the same thing here, then it makes sense to at least try it. I'll have a shot and report back. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Andre Andersen Well if he is using  "unitOfWork " the instance should not be a Singleton and the instance might not be the same even as the one in HttpContext.RequestServices from the controller.

Comment: @FilipCordas Granted, it depends on how his Repository is built. Then he should use the `services.Add` and pass it to the Controller's `ctor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rader then using reflection(Always a bad idea) I would recommend doing something like this

```
public static T Create<T>(IDocumentLibraryCreator<T> repo)// You can add you params here 
            where T:  DocumentLibrary, new()
        {
            var newItem = new T();

            repo.Create(newItem);
//Do your stuff here
            return newItem;
        }


        public interface IDocumentLibraryCreator<T> where T : DocumentLibrary
        {
            Task Create(T document);
        } 

        public abstract class DocumentLibrary
        {

        }
```

Because all you will get with reflection is runtime exceptions and not compile time exceptions. No need for reflection. Your repo will need to implement `IDocumentLibraryCreator<T>` interface but if you did IRepository in a good way you should have something like this already.
You will need to pass the instance created in the uof class if you need the work to be done in a single Unite of work.

Comment: In the end I took your advice and sent in the Generic Repo to the function. Worked a treat. Thanks!